# Receive DownloaLink from MySQL Table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, webclient

I have tried search for an ID in an MySQL table and return the associated string column which holds the URL.
But The Downloader always tells me the link format is wrong.

This is my method:

```
      public string URL(string ID)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=Downloader;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT string FROM Files WHERE ID = '" + ID + "';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader.ToString();
    }
```

And here the downloader:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql_reader sql_reader = new sql_reader();
      if (!Directory.Exists("Downloads"));
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("Downloads");
        }

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text)), "./Downloads/" + textBox2.Text + "." + textBox3.Text);
```

textBox1 is the Box where I type in the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** you need to call `Read()` function  before fetching the records from `MySqlDataReader` Object

**2.**  you have to specify the `column name` while accessing the records.

Example:

```
            String result="";
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader.Read())
            result=reader["columnname"].ToString();
```

**3.** I would suggest you to use `Parametrised Queries` to avoid `SQL injection Attacks`.

Example:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT string FROM Files WHERE ID =@ID;");             
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID);
```

**4.** `dipose` the `MySqlCommand`,`MySqlConnection` and `MySqlDataReader`  Objects properly. you can use `using{}` block to dipose them cleanly.

**Complete Code**

```
 public string URL(string ID)
        {   
            String result="";
            using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=Downloader;"))
           {
            using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT string FROM Files WHERE ID =@ID;"))
            {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID);
            using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
            if(reader.Read())
            result=reader["string"].ToString();
            else 
            result="";//you can customize here
            }
           }
          }
            return result;
        }
```

**Solution 2:**

Replace This Statement:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text)), "./Downloads/" + textBox2.Text + "." + textBox3.Text);
```

With this:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text),UriKind.Absolute), "./Downloads/" + textBox2.Text + "." + textBox3.Text);
```

Comment: Now I did the method how you posted (by the Way its in an seperate class called "sql_reader") but i dont know how to do this syntax?

Comment: @user3051872: are you able to run the code now? just replace your `URL()` with `URL()` function in my answer completely it works perfectly.

Comment: The same error : Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid. ID is abcdefg12345 and should return 127.0.0.1/test.html

Comment: @user3051872: which URL you are getting from `URL()` function , could you please debug and let me know.

Comment: @user3051872: set a break point in `URL()` function and see what is the value of status variable at the end of the function.

Comment: result is 127.0.0.1/test.html this looks perfect.

Comment: @user3051872 : Okay then there is a problem in `new Uri(sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text))` statement , is your application is web?

Comment: The error apaers when the programm return to: client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text)), "./Downloads/" + textBox2.Text + "." + textBox3.Text);

Comment: imean is your application website or windows?

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application.

Comment: Box2 is Filename and Box3 Typ (.html) and without the (sql_reader.URL(textBox1.Text)) i can download files with no problem (Direct Link).

Comment: @user3051872 : you need to add `UriKind.Absolute` in `new Uri()` function , check my edited answer with section `Solution2`.

Comment: Wow thank you everything works now. But could you tell me why I need this UriKind.Absolute ?

Comment: @user3051872: you need to specify whether the given uri is Absolute or Relative using `UriKind.Absolute` and `UriKind.Relative` respectively, here your uri is complete hence should mention as Absolute but uri is something `.projects/index.html` then should mention Relative